# Naming main assembly (.exe) to avoid long file name: Company.Product.Application.exe

Tags: .net, assemblies

**Background**

When creating general class libraries, I mirror the Microsoft .NET Framework name structure, replacing `System` with my own company name -- i.e., `Tek4.Net.NetworkWidget`.

For product-specific assemblies, I use something like `Tek4.ProductName.IO.FileWriter`.

**Output .exe file names too long!!! `Company.Product.SuperApp.exe`**

Visual Studio uses the full assembly name for output files; this is great for DLL's, but is too much for a console application -- i.e., `Tek4.Utils.ConsoleApp.exe`

### Solution 1: (NOT PREFERRED)

Forego hierarchical names for main executable assemblies:

- **Assembly name:** ConsoleApp
- **EXE File name:** ConsoleApp.exe

This solution means your delivered .exe files will only contain a simple assembly name that fails to identify itself well, and is much more subject to name collisions with other assemblies. Stack traces, .NET Reflector, etc. will only show `ConsoleApp` instead of a fully-qualified assembly name.

### Solution 2: (MY CURRENT CHOICE)

Rename the output file after compilation while retaining the full internal assembly name (using a post-build event or manual rename):

- **Assembly name:** Tek4.Utilities.ConsoleApp
- **EXE File name:** Tek4.Utilities.ConsoleApp.exe --> ConsoleApp.exe

With this solution name collision is unlikely, and anywhere the assembly name shows up (i.e., stack traces, system event logs, etc.) it is easy to identify the source.

For some reason, I still hate the clunky manual rename, though.

### Your Solutions and Practices?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also go with the shorter executable name, especially if it is expected to be used from the command line.

Having that said, what I have seen quite often, is the following convention if you have both a GUI version and a command line version of your application:

GUI:  SuperApp.exe
CLI:  SuperApp.Console.exe

FWIW

Comment: For now, I used a post-build command to rename `Tek4.ConsoleApp.Widget.exe` to `Widget.exe` -- this keeps the "fully qualified" assembly name intact for stack traces, .NET Reflector, etc., and keeps the .exe file name short.

Answer (score 1):

My practice is same as Yours. And yes I would use short SuperApp.exe for the main executable. And hey if client sees stack traces something went wrong. So he better doesn't see your company's name in it ;)

Comment: LOL! Good one. I'm attempting to create a hierarchy for my company that is always rooted with "Tek4", and also doesn't pollute the root namespace with hundreds of app names (i.e., Tek4.ConsoleApps.SuperUtil instead of Tek4.SuperUtil or just SuperUtil).

Answer (score 0):

Just a mere proposition:

```
YourCompany.YourProduct.Gui
YourCompany.YourProduct.Gui.Controllers
```

and you get the idea.

Comment: Doing that now. Please read the second part of the question (i.e., avoiding "YourCompany.YourProduct.Utility.Widget.exe").